# Pass template args by const& or &&

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this example program:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Message, typename Decoration, typename PrintImpl>
void print_surrounded(Message&& msg, const Decoration& decoration, const PrintImpl& print_impl)
{
    print_impl(decoration); // should forward be used?
    print_impl(" ");
    print_impl(std::forward<Message>(msg));
    print_impl(" ");
    print_impl(decoration);
}

template<typename Message, typename PrintImpl>
void pretty_print(Message&& msg, const PrintImpl& print_impl)
{
    print_surrounded(std::forward<Message>(msg), "***", print_impl);
}

int main()
{
    pretty_print("So pretty!", [](const char* msg) {
        std::cout << msg;
    });
}
```

[I also posted it on Coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7320f0828a53568c)

As you can see I use different ways to pass the arguments:

- Message is passed as a universal reference because it eventually needs to be forwarded to the PrintImpl function.
- Decoration is passed as const ref here because its value is used twice and I'm not sure if using forward twice would be safe. (It might be moved away by the first forward?)
- PrintImpl is passed as const reference because I don't see any reason to use forward. However, I'm not certain if this is wise. (Should I pass by `&&`? If yes, should I also use `std::forward`?)

Am I making the right choices?

Comment: This isn't exactly what I have understood CPS to mean. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style Also, in the line of the comment, I assume you are asking whether to use `forward` with `print_impl`, not `decoration`, right?

Comment: @sehe Alright, I removed the CPS parts.

Comment: Just to clarify: is "capture" the correct term here? I thought "capture" is reserved for the capturing of variables by closure objects (generated by lambda expressions). Isn't "pass" (of an argument) the correct term?

Comment: @Walter you are right. I changed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I making the right choices?

Yes (mostly).

> Decoration is captured as const ref here because its value is used twice and I'm not sure if using forward twice would be safe. (**It might be moved away by the first forward?**)

Don't use `std::forward` when you'd do it multiple times, exactly for the reason you layed out.

> PrintImpl is captured as const reference because I don't see any reason to use forward.

What you might want to do is take `PrintImpl&&` and don't use `std::forward` (keeping them as lvalues), allowing function objects without `const`-qualified `operator()` to be passed.

Comment: And, if you are extremely silly, you can `std::forward<PrintImpl>(print_impl)()` in the very last call to `print_impl` in your function, in case your `PrintImpl` has a `&&` qualified `operator()`.  (Note: nobody has a `&&` qualified `operator()`)